# complete device removal in Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, embedded, usb, stm32

I am developing USB-audio device based on STM32F429 chip using HAL and CubeMX. This device is intented to be usb-soundcard without specific features so it uses standard Windows USB audio driver. Cube generated code works just fine, the problem is: when i change device descriptor settings (like supported audio frequency, etc) Windows recognizes device, but returns an error in Device Manager:

```
Device not migrated
Device configured(usb.inf)
Device not started(usbccgp)
```

The first statement also says:

```
Device USB\VID_08DA&PID_82A7\00000002345A was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.
```

When i revert device descriptor to the initial state it was connected to PC the first time, everything works just fine. I believe the problem is Windows sees changes in device descriptor for already aknowledged device and considers it to be malfunctioned.

The question is: how can I remove all information about device installation so the system could start configuration process anew? "Device removal" option in Device Manager doesnt work - I can still see history of all events after device reconnection.

Comment: I had a similar problem during development of a USB device and used the Device Manager to remove a device from Windows. But you have to take care: Typically a USB device appears as more than just one entry in the Device Manager. In your case as Sound Card, but it may also appear in USB-Controller. Try to remove both using "Device removal".

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the problem is Windows sees changes in device descriptor for already aknowledged device and considers it to be malfunctioned.

Expected behaviour: When your descriptors change, you are supposed to use a different PID (`idProduct` in the device descriptor).

Windows uses the same driver (cached in registry) when it sees the same `idVendor`, `idProduct` and `bcdDevice` value in a device descriptor. You will need to change at least the `bcdDevice` value in your case.